# Segmentation fault - what is the reason

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, segmentation-fault, arguments

I'm learning 32bit assembly and I need help with code. I'm trying to put 4 to a table at index 3, which is passed by arguments to assebly code.

```
.code32

.equ    KERNEL, 0x80    # Linux system functions entry
.equ    WRITE,  0x04    # write data to file function
.equ    EXIT,   0x01    # exit program function

.equ    STDOUT, 1


.equ argTab,    8
.equ argLicz,   12
.equ argN,  16
.equ argZakres, 20

.text
    .globl przelicz
    .type przelicz, @function

przelicz:

    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp

    movl $2, %ecx
    movl $4, %ebx

    movl argTab(%ebp), %edx
    movl %ebx, (%edx,%ecx,4)


    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp

ret
```

I execute it with C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    const static int n = 5;
    int tab[n];
    int a;
    for(a = 0; a < n; ++a){
        tab[a] = a;
    }
    int licz[n];

    przelicz(tab, licz, 50, 50);

    for(a = 0; a < n; ++a){
        //printf("%d ", licz[a]);
    }
}
```

When I run it I get error: Segmentation fault (code dumped). I've read that I'm trying to get access to memory that doesn't exists. How can I solve this?

Comment: have you verified that the code is being compiled as a 32-bit process? it makes a big difference in this case

Comment: did you try stepping with a debugger?

Comment: @Taylor Flores - That was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @user1719194 I added an answer that may be a little more informative

Answer (score 0):

As I commented above, the problem is that the process is being compiled as a 64-bit process. This is a problem for two reasons:

1. `x64-linux` uses a different system call table than `x86-linux`. Since you aren't calling a direct system call, this probably isn't the mistake - but it's something to be aware of. 
   For example, `write` isn't `0x04` in `x64-linux`, it is `0x01`. (See [this table](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64) for `x64-linux` system call numbers).
2. Obviously, `x64-linux` has larger pointer sizes. So when a 32 bit address is loaded, there is a random 32-bit upper-half of that address that may point to anywhere. This also affects values in a function's stack (they call contain 8-byte offsets, instead of 4) This is mostly likely what was causing the problem in this code.